# Worklight 6.2 - Stable version of JDK and Liberty profile for Production environment

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty, ibm-jdk

I read many questions which were discussed about the Liberty profile and JDK versions for Worklight server.

Production environment[**Windows 2008 Server Standard**] needs to be setup using Worklight 6.2 with IBM DB2 10.5.

**JDK** - Oracle JDK 1.7 *or* IBM JDK 1.7

**Liberty Profile** - 8.5.5.1 *or* 8.5.5.2 *or* 8.5.5.3

I am confused which version of Java/Liberty are to be used.

Need advice to understand the impact and difference so that I can set it up properly.

Answer (score 0):

- Liberty 8.5.5.2 and 8.5.5.3 seem to have issues with Worklight 6.2, so best to stay at this time with 8.5.5.1, which works well.
- Java, 6 or 7, Oracle's or IBM's seem to work fine.
- If in development and Android is required, Studio should be set-up with Oracle's for best compatibility

Of course, you could just Try...